# Why buttons are cropped?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I use the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_text"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/dialog_title" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dialog_text"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialog_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/yes" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_no"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/no" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the following style is applied:

```
<activity
    android:name="my.package.DialogActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:label="@string/dialog_title"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

In some cases (depends on the `dialog_text` length?), buttons are cropped.

What is the reason? How could it be fixed?

Comment: Try to remove the margin bottom from your buttons and layouts

Comment: Once decrease the number of lines in dialog_text to 1 or 2 lines and see your buttons not cropped.

Comment: i tried your code without style. its working perfect even so many lines and buttons not cropped. In your case problem is in theme i think its has fixed height. so you can change its height to stop crop problem.

Comment: The solution given by @Haresh below works well. The dialog theme doesn't have fixed height - at least the height is changed depending on the text length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_text"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/dialog_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_yes"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/yes" />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_no"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/no" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't help - (the text is dynamic) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb5uxtir9c7t6mh/device-2013-10-05-145425.png.

Comment: Thanks for new edition. I've added `android:paddingLeft="10dp"` and `android:paddingRight="10dp"` to the parent `LinearLayout` - now it looks well.

Answer (score 2):

In `<RelativeLayout>` as text lines increase the buttons below cropped. Recently i faced this problem too. As your `TextView` in `<RelativeLayout>`. Either write `TextView` in `<LinearLayout>` or set the number of lines of text. so that Button size not crop.

Try this in your `onCreate()` method of your activity class-

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();  
params.x = -20;  
params.height = 100;  
params.width = 550;  
params.y = -10;  

this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

you can set height width according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I don't now number of lines since the text is dynamic. What should be the layout if I put `TextView` into `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Change android:layout_height="wrap_content" to something dp like 250 dp in <RelativeLayout>. if still cropping then increase dp. hope its work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set Bottom margin for button.

Comment: No, it doesn't help - buttons are still cropped.

Comment: remove layout_weight option in button tag